# Expression / phrase for a reply to ridiculous assumption

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

The expression for a reply to a ridiculous assumption, that someone makes, which makes you chuckle.

Example:
- ...healthy food like salads, fish and...
- burgers?
- no, ->**expression**<- *(laughing)*

Comment: There are any number of ways of being dismissive in such contexts (including non-verbal ones such as *laughing*, and *rolling one's eyes*). One expression that comes to mind is *Don't be (so) daft!*, but if you want a single word you could consider, for example, ***Hardly**!* In many contexts, a natural way to *describe* the act of delivering such a response might be *He **laughed it off***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks, but I am looking for the one, that could be used in speech. And it should be an expression of phrase, not a single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common reply when someone makes a ridiculous assumption, or statement is [**.. and pigs might fly**](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/pigs-might-fly.html) or something similar like **'only if pigs have wings'**.

Another idiom: **If wishes were horses, beggars would ride**, needs a more appropriate context, but could apply if the assumption was a speculative/hopeful one.

Comment: Could you, please, suggest other ways of replying, which are similar to your initial answer, that is semantically indirect and snappy, which is exactly what I'm looking for.? I think you understood, what I'm looking for, the closest.

Answer (score -1):

If you want phrases, you might say "you're kidding about the *the red meat being healthy food* aren't you?" or "I hope you are teasing" or "I don't think so" or Do you want to run that by me again? and leave out the part about **"